# Python datetime weird behavior

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.7, python-3.x

I trying this in Python. What is the difference of those:

```
>>> a = datetime.fromtimestamp(1373576406)
>>> a.replace(tzinfo=tzutc())
datetime.datetime(2013, 7, 12, 0, 0, 6, tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> a.strftime('%s')
'1373576406'
```

and

```
>>> datetime.fromtimestamp(1373576406).replace(tzinfo=tzutc()).strftime('%s')
'1373580006'
```

I don't really understand why this is happening. Shouldn't both timestamps be equal?

I tried these in both Python 3.3.2 and Python 2.7.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`datetime.replace` returns a **new** datetime instance.

In your first example you are ignoring the return value of `datetime.replace` and are then doing `datetime.strftime` on your old datetime instance.

This causes the inequality you are experiencing.

To make both examples equal you would have to edit the verbose one to look like:

```
>>> a = datetime.fromtimestamp(1373576406)
>>> a = a.replace(tzinfo=tzutc())
>>> a.strftime('%s')
'1373576406
```